# Is there a way to know if there is a key added or removed from an array in lua?

Tags: lua, metatable, meta-method

```lua
local t = {}
local mt = setmetatable({
        -- some meta method to know when a key is added or lost and prints a message
      }, t)
```

Is there a way of doing this. I talked about this with someone and they said i couldn't just do it with meta methods but proxies as well. I'm a bit stumped on how to make this work. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track table keys in lua there are 2 most importaint keys in metatable: `__index` and `__newindex`.

`__newindex` is used to create new key in the table if such key is not found. `__index` is used to get the value if there is no such key in table.

With `__newindex` it is possible to track creation, but not assignment, so it is not possible to track key removal:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local t={}
setmetatable(t, {
  __newindex = function(self, key, value)
    print('Added Key:'..key,'Value:'..value)
    rawset(self, key, value)
  end
})

t.test = 'test'
t.test = nil -- delete not tracked
t.test = 'test2'

</script>
```

Using proxy table and `__newindex` with `__index` we can track every assignment:

```html
<script src="https://github.com/fengari-lua/fengari-web/releases/download/v0.1.4/fengari-web.js"></script>
<script type="application/lua">

local t={}
local proxytable={}
setmetatable(t, {
  __newindex = function(self, key, value)
    if proxytable[key] then
      if value == nil then
        print('Deleted Key:'..key)
      else
        print('Changed Key:'..key,'Value:'..value)
      end
    else
      print('Added Key:'..key,'Value:'..value)
    end
    rawset(proxytable, key, value)
  end,
  __index = proxytable
})

t.test = 'test'
t.test = nil
t.test = 'test2'
t.test = 'test3'
t.test = nil

</script>
```

If you want enumerate table keys with `pairs()`, `ipairs()`, then you need to use metakeys `__pairs` and `__ipairs` as original table is allways empty.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!! I was at this for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

```
local tab = {}
local meta = {}

setmetatable( tab,
    {  __newindex = function( self, key, value )
          print( key, value )
          rawset( self,  key,  value  )
       end
    } )
```

`tab [1]  = 'this'`
`tab [#tab +1]  = 'that'`
`tab .the  = 'other'`
`tab [3] = nil`
`tab [4] = 2`

Comment: yea, I knew the premise, just was following text from --  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_metatables.htm --  and they had unnecessary quotes around the value.  Same thing.

Comment: That only works for inserting though, not for deleting.